# 'The command line is too long' when linking .obj files in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, maven, dll, cmd, linker

As a last step to my maven build on Windows, it tries to create a `dll` file by linking around 1500 object files. Looks something like this:

```
cl.exe foo.dll (around 1500 .obj files) (couple of other statically linked libraries)
```

The build fails with just one statement:
`The command line is too long.`

Have tried to search the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869685/gathering-list-of-file-extensions-the-command-line-is-too-long-workaround), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682799/what-to-do-with-the-input-line-is-too-long-error-message) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528099/the-command-line-is-too-long-when-running-maven-test) but the solutions are more context specific rather than something more generic. Could any one suggest what I can do?

Comment: Reorganize your program. It would be better if you packaged up some of the 1500 object files into libraries ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got the answer to my question.
I can bundle the arguments of the command in an `.rsp` file and fire it up on my command prompt with the executable after prepending its path by '@'.
So, for this command:

```
cl.exe foo.dll (around 1500 .obj files) (couple of other statically linked libraries)
```

I put this

```
foo.dll (around 1500 .obj files) (couple of other statically linked libraries)
```

inside a file say `makeDLL.txt`. Change it to a `.rsp` file by changing its extension (`makeDLL.rsp`) and fire up this command:

```
cl.exe @<full-path of makeDLL.rsp>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this one, it made my day ;) . It's also mentioned [here](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/53). Also related with this [issue](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/03/29/solving-the-8192-character-command-line-limit-on-windows/)